# Plunker is not running my Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, plunker

Created Angular CLI project, followed by Heroes demo. Locally all works fine, tried to put in on Plunker - it's not downloaded and not showing any errors. Do you have ideas what it can be?

https://plnkr.co/edit/5H7arar95E23iuFd2WCp?p=preview

index.html: (It's look like not seeing files in app directory)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>USERS</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng2-bootstrap/x.x.x/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>....</app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

plunker uses its own configurations setting.if you are curious just create new angular project from plunker and see their index.html configurations and then put you changes into plunker angular project

Comment: I saw it, I used it, also tried to make it changes for my project, and it stopped after I start to add - providers: [UserService] in app module.

Comment: if you can share you plunkr then i can go over that

Comment: so i went through you plunker code. so when you open your console you get list of 3rd party error like its not able to find @ng-bootstrap.so you can take look on how to add external pkgs to your project on plunker. if any further assistance we can go over chat

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/iSz5lfsBSXhfeC0z5QMr?p=preview please refer this link

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!